# scrollView Inside Horizontal Scrollview not working properly

Tags: android, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

Hope we have good time.dude i m stuck in a little problem .when i place vertical scroll view inside horizontal scroll view then vertical scrollview not works properly.(i tried vice verse too by placing horizontal scroll view inside vertical.)

when i try to scroll the layout just allow me to scroll in  one direction not in both simultaneously.
i think this is android genuine problem.

kindly provide any solution .
Regards

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout21"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:background="@drawable/top_bar_bg" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
            android:text=" Image card"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" Description"
            android:textSize="20sp" >
        </TextView>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/IMAGEVIEW_TEXTVEIW"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:gravity="top" >
        </EditText>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" Image"
            android:textSize="20sp" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical|fill_horizontal" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="5dip" >

                    <ScrollView
                        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="center" >

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_centerInParent="true" >

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/IMAGE_VIEW"
                                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                                    android:src="@drawable/diamond" >
                                </ImageView>
                            </RelativeLayout>
                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </ScrollView>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See Below xml.This works for me.Hope will work for you too.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <HorizontalScrollView android:id="@+id/horizontal_scroll_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:scrollbars="horizontal">


            <ScrollView android:id="@+id/vertical_scroll_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollbars="vertical">



                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TableLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/layout">
                        <!--

                            <TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" > <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="ksjdhfksjdhfksjdhfksdhfksjdhfksjdhfksjdhfkjsdhfkjsdfhkjsdfhkjhkjhkjhkjhkjhkjhkjhkjhkjhkjhkjhkjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj"
                            /> </TableRow>
                        -->
                    </TableLayout>

                    <!--
                        childrens go here.. I have used an image view for demonstration
                    -->



        </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>

    </HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @HikmatKhan: If this answer bears the same problem you had originally, and *another* answer (the one by [Nicholas](http://stackoverflow.com/users/930260/nicholas-magnussen)) solved your problem, why did you mark *this* answer here as accepted?

Answer (score 11):

There is much more simpler solution than creating a custom view:

### Layout:

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/scrollHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ScrollView 
        android:id="@+id/scrollVertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <WateverViewYouWant/>

    </ScrollView>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

### Code (onCreate/onCreateView):

```
    final HorizontalScrollView hScroll = (HorizontalScrollView) value.findViewById(R.id.scrollHorizontal);
    final ScrollView vScroll = (ScrollView) value.findViewById(R.id.scrollVertical);
    vScroll.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() { //inner scroll listener         
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    hScroll.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() { //outer scroll listener         
        private float mx, my, curX, curY;
        private boolean started = false;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            curX = event.getX();
            curY = event.getY();
            int dx = (int) (mx - curX);
            int dy = (int) (my - curY);
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (started) {
                        vScroll.scrollBy(0, dy);
                        hScroll.scrollBy(dx, 0);
                    } else {
                        started = true;
                    }
                    mx = curX;
                    my = curY;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
                    vScroll.scrollBy(0, dy);
                    hScroll.scrollBy(dx, 0);
                    started = false;
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

You can change the order of the scrollviews. Just change their order in layout and in the code. And obviously instead of WateverViewYouWant you put the layout/views you want to scroll both directions.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you can achieve what you're trying to that way. Atleast not according to what I've read.

However, here is a blog by a guy who made a custom scrollview, that might fit your needs.

http://blog.gorges.us/2010/06/android-two-dimensional-scrollview/

Comment: Thanks Brother for you time.
Link is really useful and solved my problem.

Comment: @HikmatKhan: If this solved the problem, why did you mark another answer (that, by your own words, does not solve the issue) as accepted? Seems kind of unfair towards this answer's author to grant someone else the reputation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using displaying items in `RecyclerView` inside the `HorizontalScrollView`, just make it simple by adding a line of code:

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

If you have multiple `HorizontalScrollView` inside the `ScrollView` you can can use the same above code for each `RecyclerView` in `HorizontalScrollView` which is inside the `Scrollview`.